# Jenkins pipeline - edit build name on a build triggered from another pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins pipeline, that runs sereval other jobs. Something like

```
pipeline {
...

stage('Job_1') {

    build job: 'job-1', parameters: [
            ...
        string(name: 'BUILD_NAME', value: params.BUILD_NAME),
    ]
}

stage('Job_2') {

    build job: 'job-2', parameters: [
            ...
        string(name: 'BUILD_NAME', value: params.BUILD_NAME),

    ]
}
```

and job-1, job-2 being matrixJobs. I would like to set the build names using parameter passed to the parent pipeline. The job-1 looking like

```
matrixJob('job-1') {
...

parameters {
        ...
    stringParam('BUILD_NAME', "#${BUILD_NUMBER} - x", 'Name for the build')
}

wrappers {
        ...
    buildName("${BUILD_NAME}")
}

steps {
    ...
}
```

It seems in matrixJob parameters cannot be used in build name, I get error

```
ERROR: (job_1.groovy, line 39) No such property: BUILD_NAME for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.wrapper.WrapperContext
```

I would like to ask how is it possible to change the build name to add e.g. a product version. Or perhaps if there is another way to achieve this besides passing build name as a parameter.

**EDIT:**

I worked around this problem using script in parent pipeline. Something like this

```
stage('Job_1') {

    build job: 'job-1', parameters: [
            ...
    ]
}

stage('Job_2') {

    build job: 'job-2', parameters: [
            ...

    ]
}

stage('Set_names') {
    def build = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem('job-1').lastBuild
    if(build.getResult() != hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS) {
        build.displayName = params.BUILD_NAME
    }
}
```

no tweaking of child jobs was needed.

Comment: If you have found a solution, please post it as an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem using script in parent pipeline. Something like this

```
stage('Job_1') {

    build job: 'job-1', parameters: [
            ...
    ]
}

stage('Job_2') {

    build job: 'job-2', parameters: [
            ...

    ]
}

stage('Set_names') {
    def build = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem('job-1').lastBuild
    if(build.getResult() != hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS) {
        build.displayName = params.BUILD_NAME
    }
}
```

no tweaking of child jobs was needed.